# dplyr: transpose a list (length-n) in a cell to n-rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this style of data:

```
df=tibble(a=letters[23:25],b='k',c='m',d=list(runif(4)))
df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      a     b     c         d
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <list>
1     w     k     m <dbl [4]>
2     x     k     m <dbl [4]>
3     y     k     m <dbl [4]>
```

I'd like to have each value in the list `d` be an entry in a column named `m`, which is the contents of `c`.  Specifically:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 12
      a     b     m     
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>     
1     w     k     0.57 
2     x     k     0.45 
3     y     k     0.34
```

If possible I'd like to use only `dplyr`, or at least something from the `tidyverse`

Comment: i really dont understand what you want here

Comment: Isn't this a simple `tidyr::unnest(df)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::unnest` for this.

```
require(tidyverse);
unnest(df) %>%
    select(-c)
## A tibble: 12 x 3
#   a     b         d
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 w     k     0.924
# 2 w     k     0.537
# 3 w     k     0.469
# 4 w     k     0.289
# 5 x     k     0.924
# 6 x     k     0.537
# 7 x     k     0.469
# 8 x     k     0.289
# 9 y     k     0.924
#10 y     k     0.537
#11 y     k     0.469
#12 y     k     0.289
```

---

### Sample data

```
set.seed(2017);
df=tibble(a=letters[23:25],b='k',c='m',d=list(runif(4)))
```